# Change "Tab" keys instead of “Ctrl+Tab” key in TabControl

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, focus, tabcontrol, key-bindings

I'd like to switch the tabs using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> keys instead of standard <kbd>Ctrl+Tab</kbd>

My code is

```
<TabControl>
      <TabItem Header="Section 1" Name="tabSection1">
          <ScrollViewer>
               <ContentPresenter Name="cntSection1" />
           </ScrollViewer>
      </TabItem>
      <TabItem Header="Section 2" Name="tabSection2">
          <ScrollViewer>
               <ContentPresenter Name="cntSection2" />
           </ScrollViewer>
      </TabItem>            
 </TabControl>

  <StackPanel>
     <Button Content="Save" Name="btnSave"  />
      <Button Content="Cancel" Name="btnCancel" IsCancel="True" />
   </StackPanel>
```

Each of my `ContentPresenters` contains `UserControls` with multiple UI Elements such as `Textboxes` and `Checkboxes`.

So far I have tried the follow with no luck.

```
  <TabControl.InputBindings>
            <KeyBinding Key="Tab" Modifiers="Control" Command="EditingCommands.TabForward" />
  </TabControl.InputBindings>
```

And

```
 <TabControl KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Continue" KeyboardNavigation.ControlTabNavigation="None">
```

Comment: Just a curious question... how do you want your current `TabItem` to behave, when it actually has come content view and that content has focusable controls like a TextBox. So when we click `Tab` key, would you expect next `TabItem` to be selected OR you want the `Tab` key would focus controls from the current content view? This consideration should matter, when you are asking for behavior like this.

Comment: When the Tab Key is pressed it should move the focus to the controls in the current content view. When the last item is reached the next TabItem should be made visible.

Comment: I would suggest to achieve this using custom behaviors. `TabControl`'s functionality to use `Control + Tab key` to switch between `TabItems` is specific. I am skeptical if someone can override that using any settings.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented something similar where I wanted the tab key to change tabs when the last textbox in the tab was currently focused.  I used the following Attached Behavior:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Core.Common
{
    public static class ChangeTabsBehavior
    {
        public static bool GetChangeTabs(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(ChangeTabsBehaviorProperty);
        }

        public static void SetChangeTabs(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(ChangeTabsBehaviorProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ChangeTabsBehaviorProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ChangeTabs",
                typeof(bool), typeof(ChangeTabsBehavior),
                new PropertyMetadata(false, OnChangeTabsChanged));

        private static void OnChangeTabsChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var textBox = (FrameworkElement) sender;

            var changeTabs = (bool) (e.NewValue);

            if (changeTabs)
                textBox.PreviewKeyDown += TextBoxOnPreviewKeyDown;
            else
                textBox.PreviewKeyDown -= TextBoxOnPreviewKeyDown;
        }

        private static void TextBoxOnPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs keyEventArgs)
        {
            if (keyEventArgs.Key == Key.Tab)
            {
                var textBox = (FrameworkElement) sender;
                var tabControl = textBox.TryFindParent<TabControl>();

                if (tabControl.SelectedIndex == tabControl.Items.Count - 1)
                    tabControl.SelectedIndex = 0;
                else
                    tabControl.SelectedIndex++;

                keyEventArgs.Handled = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See http://www.hardcodet.net/2008/02/find-wpf-parent for the TryFindParent method

You then attach the behavior in XAML like so:

```
<TextBox local:ChangeTabsBehavior.ChangeTabs="True"/>
```

You should be able to modify this pretty easily for your needs.

More on behaviors here: http://www.jayway.com/2013/03/20/behaviors-in-wpf-introduction/